# How to switch from RDP user login to local user login with Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8, remote-desktop, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a Windows 8.1 desktop PC where I log into using RDP. Now I want to use Moonlight (Android app) that also uses some of the remote protocols used by RDP. Besides that Moonlight also uses Nvidia services to function.

The following problem arises:

1) The Nvidia services don't run when the PC is on the login screen of Windows

This means I need to log myself in, ofcourse I want to do this remotely.

2) When I do this using RDP, Moonlight won't function since some of the RDP services are already in use.

3) When I log off from the RDP session it still does not work since the computer is logged in with my users credentials but still as a RDP user which means that some special display drivers are loaded instead of the Nvidia ones which are used when doing a regular local log in.

Is there a way to login over RDP then switching that user over to the local version of that user (and breaking off the RDP connection). Or put in another way how do I let my computer login to my local ('real') user account remotely?

The only thing I could think off is removing password login and then just reboot the system remotely. But because of security reasons I don't want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This utility solves the problem but relies on removing password login so it is not ideal:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/autologon.aspx

After rebooting with this utility enabled I can use Moonlight Nvidia game streaming over the Internet as intended.

The problem with this utility is that this setting remains until you manually change it back. I think a powershell script should be able to do the following:

1) remove need for password

2) reboot

3) re-enable need for password

And do all this without writing the username/password combination down in plain text somewhere ;)